# Javascript toggle class on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have this HTML structure

```
<div class="sType_click">
    <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sType_click">
    <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sType_click">
    <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I use JavaScript to toggle class on `sType_click` div with the `customText` span BUT without adding it on other `sType_click` divs?

For example if I click on one of the `customText` class I want to toggle class on its parent `sType_click` div and not adding on any others.

I currently use this

```
var sType_click = document.querySelector(".sType_click"),
customText = document.querySelector(".customText"),
if (null !== document.querySelector(".customText")) {
    customText.onclick = function() {
        sType_click.classList.toggle("sOpen");
    };
}
```

But this toggles all `sType_click` divs on the page 
I'm okay with jQuery but i prefer pure javascript, 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can make it with jquery so much easier:

```js
$('.fw_customText').on('click', function() {
     $(this).closest(".sType_click").toggleClass("sOpen");
});
```

```css
.sOpen{
   background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sType_click">
        <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="fw_customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sType_click">
        <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="fw_customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sType_click">
        <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="fw_customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS solution:

You should listen for clicks on `customText` elements and get 2 levels higher using `parentNode` twice. Also, use `querySelectorAll` to get all elements (non-live list, so it doesn't update when you toggle class).

```js
var fwcustomText = document.querySelectorAll(".sType_click .customText");
      
for (var ct of fwcustomText) { // listen to clicks on ".customText" elements
  ct.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.toggle("sType_click"); // toggle class 2 levels higher
  })
}
```

```css
.sType_click {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sType_click">
        <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sType_click">
        <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sType_click">
        <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you retrieve also these elements? `var sType_click = document.querySelectorAll(".sType_click"),` They seem to not be used anywhere

Comment: @quirimmo In this html structure we always need to toggle class on wrappers, so I don't think it's necessary unless question author says otherwise.

Comment: @quirimmo I've updated the answer so it becomes more common, following your comment.

Comment: Thank you :) and sorry, I forgot to chnage some of the class names on my post, I have fixed it anyways But i think i will go with the jQuery @SilverSurfer posted :) Once again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

its easy, Just add an event click to the object

es:

```
<div class="sType_click" onclick="sType_click_eve(this)">
    <div class="Switcher">
    <span class="fw_customText">Custom text</span>
</div>
```

And on the page

```
function sType_click_eve(ele){
      var sType_click = ele,
      customText = document.querySelector(".customText"),
      if (null !== document.querySelector(".customText")) {
         customText.onclick = function() {
            sType_click.classList.toggle("sOpen");
         };
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you use jQuery because it requires less code as compare to javascript.

Check below snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.customText', function() {
  $(this).closest(".sType_click").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sType_click">
  <div class="Switcher">
    <span class="customText">Custom text</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sType_click">
  <div class="Switcher">
    <span class="customText">Custom text</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sType_click">
  <div class="Switcher">
    <span class="customText">Custom text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple JS to do that getting all the elements and accessing the parent element you want to:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".fw_customText")).forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle("sType_click");
  });
});
```

```css
.sType_click{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="sType_click">
    <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="fw_customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sType_click">
    <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="fw_customText ">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sType_click">
    <div class="Switcher">
      <span class="customText">Custom text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IE/Edge don't support `.forEach` for `NodeList`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: yeah Array.from would allow support for IE too