# Add / remove class one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make it so that in one click I can add class when I open div and delete the class when I close it? I use the readmore js library, and in the callback function I want to specify.
HTML:

```
<div class="around-about-us">
    <span class="contact-header"><?php _e('About us', 'slotsfans') ?></span>
    <div class="text toggle-text toggle-over">
        more text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .toggle-over {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .toogle-height {
    height: 100% !important;
  }
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.toggle-text').readmore({
        moreLink: '<a href="#" class="show_after"><p class="pattern-btn-underline read_more_btn">Read more</p></a>',
        lessLink: '<a href="#" class="show_after"><p class="pattern-btn-underline read_more_btn">test</p></a>',
        collapsedHeight: 534,
        speed: 1500,
        beforeToggle: function () {
           $(".toggle-text").removeClass("toggle-over").addClass('toogle-height');

       }
   });
});
```

Comment: use jquery `toggleClass`

Comment: @JonathanHamel can you explain, how right make it?

Comment: No offense but the question you are asking has been asked around a million times. If you would have googled for the exact same question, you would have gotten an answer within 5 seconds. In the future, please use stackoverflow for specific questions that you could not solve by investing 5 seconds into google.

Comment: @spyro Unfortunately I tried all the options, but nothing helps, because of this I turned to help

Comment: @spyro Thanks a lot, problem is solved

Comment: @JonathanHamel Thanks for code, i try it's working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript toggle class on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348912/javascript-toggle-class-on-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [jonathan hamel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5842628/jonathan-hamel) suggested in the comments

**Try -**

```
$(".toggle-text").toggleClass("toggle-over")
$(".toggle-text").toggleClass("toggle-height")
```

Comment: I tried before, but when toggled height is not change initial size.

Comment: The problem is that, at that time, the library add the height as 5600 px, because of this I want to add the class height: 100%! Important, but when closing, remove the height

Comment: If you already were able to remove and add the class, then please delete your question here and ask a new one with the real question. What you are writing now seems to be a pure CSS problem with no relation to javascript code (because that is already working).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example for us to work with

Comment: @spyro Help me please and i will delete the question